# JLine system terminal issue

Tags: java, jline

I have a problem with JLine 3.9.0. I created a terminal

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder().encoding("UTF-8").system(true).build();
```

First of all it shows a lot of errors, to be precise:

```
WARNING: Unable to retrieve infocmp for type dumb-color
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "infocmp": CreateProcess error=2, 
Cannot find the specified file
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.jline.utils.InfoCmp.getInfoCmp(InfoCmp.java:547)
    at org.jline.terminal.impl.AbstractTerminal.parseInfoCmp(AbstractTerminal.java:187)
    at org.jline.terminal.impl.DumbTerminal.<init>(DumbTerminal.java:88)
    at org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.doBuild(TerminalBuilder.java:404)
    at org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.build(TerminalBuilder.java:262)
    at agh.cs.Court.main.main(main.java:35)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Cannot find the specified file
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 7 more
```

But despite that the program seems to work ALMOST correctly: even after setting encoding to UTF-8 it doesn't see the characters of my alphabet, which is the second issue.